# Autollenar el formulario de actualización en django (User)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hice un modelo con el que tengo varios registros, e hice una vista basada en clases(UpdateView) que cuando ingreso a ella desde la url me carga los datos ya registrados en el formulario de actualización.

Todo excelente, pero para el modelos User de django cuando intento hacer lo mismo, el autollenado no funciona, y ya lo he intentado con vista basada en funciones y tampoco da. Ayuda (soy nuevo en django)

Comment: Puedes agregar las partes importantes de tu código? En lo posible un ejemplo de lo que sí funciona y lo que no.

Comment: hace falta mas  información por lo menos , estas usando UpdateView y/o FormModel para el caso en que no te funciona?